# PHP regex remove some unwanted div

Tags: php, html, regex

I want remove some div with id or class which contain words `comment` or `share` (like:`<div id="comment">`, `<div class="header-comment">`, `<div id="comment-footer">`, `<div class="social-share">`), something I use

```
preg_replace('/<div[^>]*(comment|share)[^>]*>(.*?)<\/div>/is', '', $htmls);
```

Not work. How to do a right regex? Here is some test code, I want to remove `comment` part and keep `content` and `footer`,

```
$htmls = <<<EOT
<div id="content">
     Main content.
</div>
<div id="comment">
    <ul>
        <li class="comment">
            <div class="header-comment">
                Comment:
                <span class="date-comment">8/11/2012, 21:25</span>
            </div>
            <h4>Some Text</h4>
            <p class="test-comment">Blah~~ Blah~~ Blah~~</p>
            <div class="share">
                <div class="vote">
                    <a class="vota yes" title="Like">2</a>
                    <a class="vota no" title="Unlike">0</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="comment">
            <div class="header-comment">
                Comment:
                <span class="date-comment">8/11/2012, 23:08</span>
            </div>
            <h4>Other Text</h4>
            <p class="test-comment">Blah~~ Blah~~ Blah~~</p>
            <div class="share">
                <div class="vote">
                    <a class="vota yes" title="Like">4</a>
                    <a class="vota no" title="Unlike">0</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>     
     </ul>
</div>
<div id="footer">
     Footer content.
</div>
EOT;

$htmls = preg_replace('/<div[^>]*(comment|share)[^>]*>(.*?)<\/div>/is', '', $htmls);
echo $htmls;
```

Comment: [Beware of parsing HTML with regular expressions, the way Cthulhu wants you to.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: A baby seal gets horribly killed every time you try to parse HTML with regex.

Comment: Html is not a regular language and therefore it is really difficult to use regular expressions to parse it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i think you should use is  `DomDocument` try :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($htmls);
$remove = array("comment","share");
$removeList = array();
foreach ( $dom->getElementsByTagName("div") as $div ) {
    if (in_array($div->getAttribute("class"), $remove) || in_array($div->getAttribute("id"), $remove)) {
        $removeList[] = $div;
    }
}

foreach ( $removeList as $div ) {
    $div->parentNode->removeChild($div);
}

$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo "<pre>";
echo htmlentities($dom->saveHTML());
```

Comment: so if some div like: `div.header-comment` ,`div.social-share`, I should list them all in `$remove = array("comment","share","header-comment","social-share");`? this is so tired to list all in an array.

Comment: is it possible use `strpos` to instead of `in_array`? if find `comment` or `share` in id or class, remove div?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.ph) functions to parse the HTML, then target the `div` you don't want and [remove](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php) it. This will be faster, easier to understand and maintain and possibly faster to write.

Answer (score 0):

> How to do a right regex?

You do so by [first identifying all DIVs, extract their texts](http://php.net/DOMXpath) and then look into that text for your regular expression pattern with [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match).

However you can spare the part with the regular expression as well and just use the *xpath*. That is more straight forward in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this site to test your REGEX
  http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html